# Div move using jquery animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I just want to move a `div` when the user chooses to. When the user clicks on a link, the `div` appears, moving from right to left. Then there is another link inside the `div`, when the user clicks on it, the `div` should move to left to right and disappear.

Following is the jQuery code I've tried:

```
$('#show').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div').show().animate({ 'left': 0 }, 300;
});   

$('#hide').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div').animate({'left': 2050}, 300,function() {$('div').hide()});
});
```

Fiddle also attached, http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/JNBAn/

Comment: You forgot a `)` after 300.

Comment: Updated the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/sameerast/JNBAn/1/

Comment: Is the behavior you're now seeing in the fiddle not what you're expecting? It seems to be doing what you're describing, but maybe I'm not understanding completely.

Comment: @brandwaffle with that solution, It works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As noted above, this just needs a comma on the 4th line, then the fiddle starts working:

```
$('#show').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div').show().animate({ 'left': 0 }, 300);
});   

$('#hide').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div').animate({'left': 2050}, 300,function() {$('div').hide()});
});
```

As a side note, I find the JavaScript Console in Chrome to be very helpful in this regard...check it out through View -> Developer -> JavaScript Console (in this case it was showing an unexpected ; error because of the missing parenthesis).

Answer (score 2):

I advise you to pay attention to the css animation. See this example: http://slides.html5rocks.com/#css-transitions

Answer (score 1):

Beside the missing parenthesis.  [Here's an updated code](http://jsfiddle.net/JNBAn/7/) to makes the div show from right to left and then hides from left to right.

JS: (Missing parenthesis)

```
$('#show').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div').show().animate({'left': 0 }, 300);
});   

$('#hide').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $('div').animate({'left': 2050}, 300,function() {$('div').hide()});
});  ​
```

CSS:

```
div{
    width:100px; 
    height:100px;
    background:#333;
    color:#999;
    position:absolute;
    top:10px;
    left:2050px;
    text-align:center;
    display:none;
}​
```

Hope this helps!